Switching from dual monitor setup and single display and back
I use extended display most of the time but when I need to go to a meeting I'm stuck on 1 screen.
Is there a 3rd party tool or feature I can use within windows that will return my display to extended screen and snap back all my apps?
When I return to my desk I want my applications to pop back into original location (remember placement across all screens)
Outlook on screen #1 full screen
RDP full screen #2 full screen
Office Tools screen #3
ect......
